# Change docker status to "Exited" i.e shutdown container upon internal process check

Tags: docker, status

I have a docker container that runs a custom php file or say a unix shell script.

If the script executes fine the docker container should continue to RUN however, if the script fails due to error or due to a custom check; then I wish to terminate (stop) i.e change the status of that docker container to "Exited".

Sample case 1: The unix shell script periodically checks for a particular file or data on a file-system / URL. If that data / file is not found I would like the docker container to shutdown (Exit status) else it should continue to run.

Sample case 2: The script runs and checks for stuck thread count for a different process. If the stuck thread count is more than 5 I would like the docker process to shutdown (Exit status) else it should continue to run.

I know how to shutdown a container from outside however, in this case I wish to trigger container shutdown from within the container depending upon the custom script's failure condition being met.

Can you please suggest ?

Comment: A typical container only runs one process, and when it exits, the container is done.  You could have an entrypoint script that does some pre-flight checks and then launches the main container process, or exits.  Can you say a little bit more about your overall container/process design?

Comment: Updated the OP with sample cases.

Answer (score 0):

Every Docker container has some main process, whatever was launched as the ENTRYPOINT or CMD.  That process has pid 1, with the rights and responsibilities that entails.  The lifetime of the container is exactly the length of that main process: the only way to cause the container to exit is to cause pid 1 to exit.  Since pid 1 is special, [it may not work to `kill 1`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7441/can-root-kill-init-process).

If I was going to implement this, I'd write a program (probably in C) that could both execute the health checks and run the main process.  If the process exited normally, the supervisor would **wait**(2) for it and then exit itself, causing the container to exit.  If a health check failed, the supervisor would **kill**(2) its child, **wait**(2) for it, and then exit itself.

I'm not immediately aware of a prebuilt implementation of this concept.  It is not dissimilar from what [supervisord](https://supervisord.org) does, except that supervisor expects to run as an init process that never exits.

Another possibility is to implement the health checks within your application itself.  Then you're just running the one process, and if a health check fails, it can kill itself (**exit**(3), for example).  Higher-level orchestrators like Kubernetes also have a health check concept that can be tied to a network request or a command that runs inside a container (for Kubernetes, see [Container probes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-lifecycle/#container-probes)).

Comment: In mycase the process is little different ...it runs interactively and never exits itself.It would exit only when a certain condition is met.